# Why can't I grep this command line option?

Tags: grep, man, character-encoding

The output of `man icc` contains

```
   -Ldir

          Tells the linker to search for libraries...
```

Doing `man icc | grep "\-L"` gives back the "-Ldir" line while `man icc | grep "\-Ldir"` does not. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Btw the title is very generic but since I have no clue what the problem is I couldn't think of a better one. Maybe if I'll get an answer I'll be able to improve it.

Comment: does `man icc | grep -e "\-Ldir"` work?

Comment: No it does not. I also tried `man icc | grep -- "-Ldir"` and it did not work.

Comment: Does `man icc | grep -e "-L" | cat -v` show anything between  `-L` and `dir` ?

Comment: Indeed it does: `-^H-L^HLd^Hdi^Hir^H`. I did not think of the usage of unprintable characters inside words. Accepted the answer of terdon as it points in the same direction.

Comment: That's how programs like `nroff` (which `man` uses) produce boldface characters on printing terminals.  When searching for text in such documents, you can pipe the output of `man` through `col -b` to remove the overstriking before piping it to `grep`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second command fails because there is probably a non-printing character between the `L` and `dir`. I can't tell you what since I don't have `icc` or its man page but you can test this by running

```
man icc | grep '\-L' | od -c
```

That will probably show something between the `-L` and the `dir`.

By the way, many programs, including `grep` use `--` to signify the end of options and everything after `--` is not parsed as an option. Therefore, you don't need the quotes:

```
man icc | grep -- -L
```

Comment: You are right. Running your `od` command revealed that many "`\b`" chars are used in the man page inside words for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

http://scv.bu.edu/computation/bladecenter/manpages/icc.html

Shows the man page as

```
-L<dir>
```

and not

```
-Ldir
```

What does man icc | grep "\-L.dir" return?

Comment: Unfortunately it returns nothing. The man excerpt I included in my answer is copy pasted from the man page as it appears on my machine.

Comment: man gcc | /bin/grep "\-Ldir" works properly on my system.  (I don't have icc installed.)  Try entering bash and executing your original command with the full path to grep.